# Cannot import file in preload

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, electron

for some reason I cannot import js files in preload.js (electron).
Error: `Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module:` 
preload.js:

```
const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron');
const repo = require("./lib/test.mjs")

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

})
```

test.mjs:

```
const request = require('request')

class Repository {
    constructor(repoUrl){
        this.repoUrl = repoUrl
        request ({
            url: this.repoUrl,
            json: true
        }, (error, response, body) =>{
            !error && response.statusCode === 200
                ? this.repoSettings = body
                : console.log(error)
        })
    }
}

module.exports = {Repository}
```

According to my research, this should work. adding `"type": "module"` to package.json only breaks things further.

Comment: In test.mjs, you're improperly loading the `'request'` module. It should be `import request from 'request';`. Similarly, you are incorrectly exporting `Repository`. It should be `export default Repository;`

Comment: @AluanHaddad fixing it, and removing the last line unfortunately produces the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue fixed by renaming `test.mjs` to `test.js`.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone faces a similar issue where (module is not found). If you check the [documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/sandbox#preload-scripts) you will find the following:

> A require function similar to Node's require module is exposed, but can only import a subset of Electron and Node's built-in modules.

> Because the require function is a polyfill with limited functionality, you will not be able to use CommonJS modules to separate your preload script into multiple files. If you need to split your preload code, use a bundler such as webpack or Parcel.

If you are using the current version of electron the problem is from **sandboxing** and **nodeIntegration**. If you *allow nodeIntegration* or *disable sandboxing*, you will be able to import the files you want, however this is not recommended for [security reasons](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/security#2-do-not-enable-nodejs-integration-for-remote-content) because according to my understanding it allows the renderer process access to low level OS methods.

The better approach would be to do as the documentation recommends, using a **bundler** you can divide your preload and even make your electron files typescript (main.ts & preload.ts). If you need help figuring out how, I would recommend checking this [repo](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate), I think it does something similar.